# Minicart - Html text reflecting raw , required formatted text in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, mini-cart

In mini cart i am trying to put a custom/formatted text but it reflecting raw html over there, required for magento 2.

Using Magento 2.2.4.

I expect html formatted text but the actual output raw text on minicart

Detail Page

[image: Detail Page]

Minicart

[image: Minicart]

Comment: why you have put html on a field? i

Comment: you don't want html allowed in there. This will open your website to vulnerabilities.

Comment: i want to add some product options like monogram design with color.